# How to build composite expression in c#?

Tags: c#, expression

I need to build an expression for the following:

```
numberings(n=>configs.All(c=>c.Field1!=n.Field1 || c.Field2!=n.Field2 || ...))
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
 BinaryExpression expression = null;
 foreach (var criteria in SelectionCriteria)
        {
            Expression<Func<Numbering, TConfiguration, bool>> exp = (_, c) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(_);
            expression = expression == null ? Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, exp, exp) : Expression.OrElse(expression, exp);
        }
        if (expression == null) return Result.Failure(string.Format(Errors.NumberingFieldSelectionNotDefined, $"{shipper}:{GetType().FullName}"));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TConfiguration, bool>>(expression);
        numberingsToRemove = numberingsToRemove.Where(_ => configsThatStay.All(lambda));
```

And here is where I got stuck. Compiler says:

> The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Func<TNumbering,TConfiguration,System.Boolean> and 'System.Func<TNumbering,TConfiguration,System.Boolean>

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have numbered fields like that, enough that you need to think about using a `...` ellipsis when describing them, you should think about a collection property like a `List` or `Array` instead. That would allow you to use a [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) operation to compare them:

```
numberings.Select(n => configs.All(c => c.Fields.Zip(n.Fields, (c1,n1) => c1!=n1).All());
```